# curvetext.js not working in any text animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I had used arched text for my main headings. I have used script from below location:

http://circletype.labwire.ca/

**This my working fiddle for rounded text:**

http://jsfiddle.net/60rz99zu/

```
$('#main-content').circleType({radius: 1000});
```

I want the heading change like this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n4mKw/

I tried many script. But animation not working. This is my animation fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/60rz99zu/1/

```
var quotes = $(".quotes");
var quoteIndex = -1;
function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
}

showNextQuote();
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have not changed the class name for the respective class, Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/60rz99zu/4/)

```
(function() {
    $('#main-content').circleType({
        radius: 1000
    });
    var textCenter = $(".text-center");
    var quoteIndex = -1;
    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        textCenter.eq(quoteIndex % textCenter.length)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }
    showNextQuote();
})();
```

Comment: I want to change the heading text. I need to rotate different headings.